# Como faço para rodar aplicativo IONIC 3 no emulador IOS?

Tags: ionic, app, apple, ionic3

Para o android deu certo, aí tentei usar o mesmo padrão pro IOS e não consegui.

1 - ionic cordova platform add ios

2 - ionic cordova run ios --emulator

Deu o BUILD SUCCEEDED mas não rodou no emulador

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, ao invés de tirar print, ou foto, execute o comando com a opção --verbose no final "ionic cordova run ios --emulator --verbose" e cole o resultado nos detalhes da pergunta. Também rode o comando "ionic info" para que possamos saber a versão do ionic, node e ios.

Comment: Tem como copiar o erro do terminal ao invés de postar foto e tem como postar o source?

Comment: Opa, obrigado galera. Consegui resolver. Vou postar a resposta aqui. Vlw